# Difference between yaml.load and yaml.SafeLoader in PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml

Python newbie here.

I installed PyYAML and tried using this bit of code I found modified on the net to parse a YAML file I was given.

```
import yaml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        foo = open("foo.txt","a+")
    except:
        print("Error in opening file.")

stream = open("s.yaml", 'r')
dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
#dictionary = yaml.SafeLoader(stream)
for key, value in dictionary.items():

    foo.write(key + " : " + str(value)+"\n")
```

Then I saw in the output that yaml.load was deprecated because of security issues. So I tried running it using SafeLoader instead. But that gave me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\parseYAML.py", line 11, in <module>
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
AttributeError: 'SafeLoader' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I can't post the actual data file here for business reasons, but does anyone have any hints on how I can get SafeLoader to work?

Comment: It should be `yaml.safe_load(stream)`. `yaml.SafeLoader` is a class. See https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the following snippets of code that show some ways to use the SafeLoader:  (the last line is probably what you're most interested in, for the simplest case)

```
import yaml

env_variable_matcher = re.compile(r'<your custom pattern here>')

def env_variable_parser(loader, node):
    '''
    Parse a yaml value containing ${A-Z0-9_} as an environment variable
    '''
    ...
    return output

# Add support for yaml tag named env_var which matches a string containing
# an environment variable.  The environment variable will be replaced with its value
yaml.add_implicit_resolver('!env_var', env_variable_matcher, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
yaml.add_constructor('!env_var', env_variable_parser, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

with open(config_file, 'r') as c_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(c_file)
```

Comment: Hello @Starman is there a reason why you didn't close the opened config file after you safe loaded it.

Comment: Hi @OzanKurt, If you mean the `open` in the "with" statement, this is making use of the convenience of context managers.  I believe there is an `.__exit__()` statement automatically executed after the indented `with` block is finished, and this would contain a close()

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of using SafeLoader

```
from yaml import SafeLoader

with open('../config.yaml') as file:
    config = yaml.load(file, Loader=SafeLoader)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OPs question was about the error. The error was caused because the OP treated the loaded result as a dictionary, when it wasn't. The loader returns what the yaml describes which might, or might not be a dict.

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

path = 'path/to/some/file.yaml'
with open(path) as f:
    obj = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
    obj_type = type(obj)
    if obj_type is list: # process obj as a list
        print('Object is list with elements:')
        for val in obj:
            print(val)
    elif obj_type is dict: # process obj as a dict
        print(f'Object is dict with elements:')
        for key, val in obj.items():
            print(f'{key}:{val}')
    else:
        print(f'yaml file {path} describes unexpected object of type {obj_type}')
```